# What is the best practice approach to fetching CKReferences in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckreference

In my CloudKit setup I have a `Person` record type and each person has a `Friend` attribute which is a `CKReference` to another `Person` object.

I fetch all `Person` `CKRecord`s. I list these people in a table and list their friends with them. Currently I just take the `CKReference` and individually fetch each friend using the `recordID`.

This is the only way I can see to do it, but what would be best practice? Particularly as I am fetching potentially a very large number of friends. It seems counterintuitive to fetch all these objects individually.

I was wondering if there was a method much like CoreData, where you can choose to fetch related objects in the main fetch? So for example, when I fetch a `Person` it automatically fetched the friends too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an 'in' predicate query to fetch multiple id's. You can define a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "To_ID in %@", [recordIdMe, recordIdOther])!
```

In your case where you see the `recordIdMe` and `recordIdOther` you should have an array of valid `CKReference` objects.

In CloudKit there is no functionality to automatically fetch related records.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should collect all the RecordIDs and add a `CKFetchRecordsOperation` to the relevant database object.

You get a back a dictionary to help you match the results with the original list.